# Which PHP Array Function to Use?

Tags: php, arrays, filtering

I'm getting super confused between all the different array functions in PHP and I have no idea which is best to use in my scenario.

I have one array that lists user sign ups and one array which lists subscriptions for those users with the date the user subscribed. The user can have multiple subscriptions or not at all. An example would be:

```
$users = [
    ['user_id' => 1, 'sign_up_date' => '2020-01-01 00:00:00'],
    ['user_id' => 2, 'sign_up_date' => '2020-01-02 00:00:00'],
    ['user_id' => 3, 'sign_up_date' => '2020-01-03 00:00:00'],
    ...
];

$subscriptions = [
    ['user_id' => 1, 'subscription_category' => 'abc', 'sign_up_date' => '2020-01-01 00:01:00'],
    ['user_id' => 1, 'subscription_category' => 'def', 'sign_up_date' => '2020-01-01 00:02:00'],
    ['user_id' => 1, 'subscription_category' => 'ghi', 'sign_up_date' => '2020-01-02 00:03:00'],
    ['user_id' => 2, 'subscription_category' => 'jkl', 'sign_up_date' => '2020-01-02 00:01:00'],
    ['user_id' => 2, 'subscription_category' => 'mno', 'sign_up_date' => '2020-01-03 00:02:00'],
    ...
];
```

What I'm attempting to find is which users subscribed to any category on their sign up date. So in this case I want to find the number of items in:

```
$usersWhoSubscribedOnSignUpDate = [1, 2];
```

What I could do is something like:

```
$results = [];
foreach ($users as $user) {
    foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
        $signUpDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($user['sign_up_date']));
        $subscriptionDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($subscription['sign_up_date']));

        if ($subscription['user_id'] === $subscription['user_id'] && $signUpDate === $subscriptionDate) {
            $results[] = subscription['user_id'];
        }
    }
}
$results = array_unique($results);
```

But that's not very elegant in my eyes and I'm convinced that one of the many PHP array functions could simplify this process somehow.

`array_intersect` doesn't seem suitable because it doesn't appear to work with multi-level arrays like this.

`array_map` doesn't seem suitable because it doesn't have the ability to compare two arrays.

`array_uintersect_assoc` seems like it could be an option however I can't understand what the "additional index check" means or how to sort the data. I believe that the callback function needs to return a comparison between two objects so perhaps this could be sorted by timestamp of the `sign_up_date` property?

Comment: Maybe you can do it with SQL query if your data is stored in db?

Comment: @u_mulder due to some poor structure in the DB and the lack of resource or time to refactor it we're not able to perform the lookups in the DB efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first think I would do is modify your arrays so the users are identified by keys, (that's the first two lines). The third line reduces the subscription dates to the earliest for each user, then the fourth finds places where the sign up and earliest subscription dates match.

```
foreach( $users as $u ) { $signups[$u['user_id']] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($u['sign_up_date']) ); }
foreach( $subscriptions as $s ) { $subs[$s['user_id']][] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($s['sign_up_date']) ); }
foreach( $subs as $key => $value ) { $subs[$key] = min( $subs[$key] ); }
$results = array_keys( array_intersect_assoc( $signups, $subs ) );
```

Comment: Marked as solution because re-mapping to using user ID's as keys was a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one iteration of `$users` and one iteration of `$subscriptions`, rather than one iteration of `$subscriptions` per row in `$users`. This could represent a significant performance improvement as the number of rows increase.

First, build an associative array of user signup dates indexed by user_id, so that you do not need to iterate over it every time you need to look up a date:

```
$userDates = [];
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $userDates[$user['user_id']] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($user['sign_up_date']);
}
```

This will give you:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2020-01-01
    [2] => 2020-01-02
    [3] => 2020-01-03
)
```

Then just iterate over the subscriptions once, looking up that user's signup date as you go:

```
foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
    if (
        date('Y-m-d', strtotime($subscription['sign_up_date'])) ===
        $userDates[$subscription['user_id']]
    ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or perhaps something like:

```
array_unique(array_filter(
    $subscriptions,
    function ($subscription) use ($userDates) {
        return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($subscription['sign_up_date'])) ===
            $userDates[$subscription['user_id']];
    }
));
```

Comment: `array_column` has __third__ argument which eliminates the need of `array_combine`.

Comment: Ah neat, never used that. (But now refactored to not perform date() every time.)